# LNK2019 error in C++

Tags: c++

I'm getting this weird linker error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall Data::~Data(void)" (??1Data@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall Job::~Job(void)" (??1Job@@UAE@XZ) C:\...\Job.obj

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall List::DataNode::DataNode(class List::DataNode const &)" (??0DataNode@List@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall List::List(class List const *)" (??0List@@QAE@PBV0@@Z)    C:\...\List.obj
```

from the first error description, it might have something to do with a destructor.

I have an empty and abstract data class with a pure virtual destructor:

```
virtual ~Data()=0;
```

and a class Job which derives from data, with a trivial implementation of the destructor:

```
Job::~Job()
{
}
```

Can you spot a problem? How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide definition for a pure virtual destructor.

**C++03 12.4 Destructors**
**Para 7:**

> **A destructor can be declared virtual (10.3) or pure virtual (10.4); if any objects of that class or any derived class are created in the program, the destructor shall be defined**. If a class has a base class with a virtual destructor, its destructor (whether user- or implicitly- declared) is virtual.

Comment: What do you mean by providing a definition for a pure virtual destructor?

Comment: @user1330810: Provide a definition(which I think you call *implementation*) for it as: `~Data(){}`.Even if the destructor is pure virtual it needs a definition.

Comment: It works - thanks! I thought that the meaning of a pure function is that you don't need to implement them in the base class - is the destructor a unique case?

Comment: @user1330810: Yes, pure virtual destructor is a unique case and that is the reason I posted the Standard quotation.